# Nextjs page not revalidating

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

On my website, I have `[articleKey].tsx` page, where I download current articles from the backend and show them on the screen.

```
export async function getStaticProps({locale, req, res}) {
    const articles = await requestArticles({lang: locale})
    generateRssFeedFiles(articles, locale)
    return {
        props: {articles},
        revalidate: 5 * 60
    }
}
```

I expect it to get current data every 5 minutes. It is important because those articles change over time. But I observe that sometimes I a change is not applied for more than a day until I manually redeploy the application. So it seems, this it not refreshing every 5 minutes. How to make it better? I don't want to use `getServerSideProps` to not make users wait, but at the same time I need this page to have fresh data.

Comment: Where the website is hosted? is it a free plan or a premium plan?

Comment: "I expect it to get current data every 5 minutes" - To clarify, the revalidation only occurs if a new request comes in, it won't automatically regenerate the page by itself. After the 5 minutes window, the next request will still show the cached page, and Next.js triggers a regeneration in the background.

Comment: It is hosted on Vercel, a premium plan.

Comment: @juliomalves This is not the thing. I checked many times during the day to check if it will finally update by itself.

Comment: @MarcinM did you solve this?
I have a similar problem.